# os, objective-c, I am unable to know exactly line, by which line my app crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

My app crashes, and every time when I run app, I get a different crash randomly, and I want to know exact line by which my app is crashing, So I used Zombie Objects,and exception break point , but xcode (version 6.3.1) does not show any information about the exact line which is responsible for crash.

I get following crashes randomly (One crash at a time out of these, these crashes come randomly ):

I am getting following crashes on ipad . Please note that crash comes randomly one at a time, out of following these :

> 1)  *** -[UIViewAnimationState release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fb78bb6eb50
>
> 2) [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x18911af0 –
>
> 3) *** -[_UIFlowLayoutItem respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7e7ca1d0
>
> 4)  FlrtAlertVariation[39992:1010801] negative or zero sizes are not supported in the flow layout
>
> 5) [_UIFlowLayoutItem setItemFrame:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fcc35296310
>
> 6)  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', >reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'
>
> 7)FlrtAlertVariation[227:60b] Gesture: Failed to receive system gesture state notification before next touch
>
> 8) *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BestMatchRequester everyBodyResponseData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14662aa0'
>
> 9)*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView recieved layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist:  {length = 2, path = 1 - 0}'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x2f780fd3 0x3a31fccf 0x2f780ead 0x3012dd5b 0x31ff8fa3 0x31ff85c7 0x31ff805d 0x31f9cd79 0x31c1a62b 0x31c15e3b 0x31c15ccd 0x31c156df 0x31c154ef 0x31c0f21d 0x2f74c2a5 0x2f749c49 0x2f749f8b 0x2f6b4f4f 0x2f6b4d33 0x345da663 0x3200016d 0x2a2bd9 0x3a82cab7)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>
> 10) *** error for object 0x156f8ea0: pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>
> 11) *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.137/UICollectionViewData.m:357
>
> 12)*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView recieved layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist:  {length = 2, path = 1 - 0}'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show me error screen short ? I think some of the object release at run time.

Comment: Add crashlytics to your project. It will show more information about the crash. It shows the line number where it is crashed..

Comment: Thanks @ Mitul and  Vidhyanand, I already used crashlytics in my project, but did not get any proper information , crashlytics show error/crash in apple library . For example it shows error/crashes in 
 
1) QuartzCore
CA::release_objects(X::List<void const*>*)

2)  UIKit
-[UICollectionViewData _updateItemCounts]

3)  UIKit
-[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]

4) UIKit
-[UICollectionViewData _setLayoutAttributes:atGlobalItemIndex:]
 
5) UIKit__45-[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:]_block_invoke

6)MBProgressHUD.m line 546
-[MBProgressHUD hideUsingAnimation:]

Answer (score -1):

The two possibilities are that either your code is quite bad and you have bugs all over the place, or more likely, you have some systematic problem.

I recommend that you first turn on all reasonable warnings in your project and fix all the problems that give warnings. Then you should use the static analyser to fix all problems that the static analyser finds.

If things still crash, then it is quite likely that you do things on a background thread that should only happen on the main thread. Doing things on a background thread that need to be done on the main thread is an excellent way to cause all kinds of random crashes as you experience them. In that situation, debugging the crashes is pointless, because the point of the crash is nowhere near the point of your bug.

Comment: Thanks @ gnasher , please let me know which warnings (name ) I should Enable for my project

Comment: May anybody help me please ?